# group by column and show ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I need to group invoices by column personne_id and show invoice ids concatenated.

```
SELECT
ARRAY_AGG("factures"."id"), "factures"."personne_id"
FROM
    "factures"
GROUP BY
    "factures"."personne_id",
    "factures"."id"
limit 100
```

But this returns

```
{16}    6
{15}    6
{14}    6
{11}    6
{10}    6
```

What I need is

```
{16, 15, 14, 11, 10}    6
```

6 is personne_id

Thanks

Comment: Remove `"factures"."id"` from the `group by`

Comment: `GROUP BY x, y` means "I want one result row per x and y". But you want one result row per `personne_id` only, so change the clause accordingly. You can remove all those double quotes from your query by the way, they are not needed.